# problems reading SAC file using obspy

Tags: python, obspy

I'm trying to read a .SAC file using obspy with this code

```
from obspy import read as obsread

st = obsread('II.NNA.00.BH1.M.2023.215.221206.SAC', debug_headers=True)
```

but I'm getting

```
TypeError: Unknown format for file II.NNA.00.BH1.M.2023.215.221206.SAC
```